# Alternativa al COALESCE / ISNULL como predicado para posibilitar uso de index

Tags: sql, sql-server

mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con un banco de datos que tiene varias tablas muy grandes, estoy hablando de mas de 100 millones de registros.

Consegui mejorar mucho el rendimiento utilizando indexados: clustered index en mi RID, nonclustered index en columnas comunmente usadas en las consultas y storedcolumn en las columnas que utilizo con las funciones de agregación.

Estas tablas son utilizadas para generar reportes, y varios de estos reportes utilizan multiples filtros de datos por lo que siempre vino bien a la mano utilizar COALESCE:

```sql
CREATE  PROCEDURE MY_PROC
(
   @id_ciudad int = null,
   @id_estado int = null,
   @id_barrio int = null,
   @id_zona_operacional int = null,
   ... otros parametros
)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT
   result_1,
   result_2,
   ...
   result_n
FROM
   MY_HUGE_TABLE
WHERE
   id_ciudad = coalesce(@id_ciudad, id_ciudad)   
and
   id_estado = coalesce(@id_estado, id_estado)
and
   id_barrio = coalesce(@id_barrio, id_barrio)
and
   id_zona_operacional = coalesce(@id_zona_operacional, id_zona_operacional)
and
   ... algunos otros filtros

END
```

El problema viene al utilizar coalesce o isnull como predicado en estas procedures, pues invalidan el uso de los index resultando en un scan y no en un seek, perdiendo mucho en rendimiento.

Como una posible solución pense en lo siguiente:

1. Crear una variable en mi SP que contenga el codigo de la query, ejemplo:

```sql
DECLARE @TSQL_QUERY as VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT <lista de colunas> FROM <tabela> WHERE 1=1'
```

2. Para cada parametro que se pase en mi SP como filtro adicionar adicionar a mi variable una condicion:

```sql
IF @filtro_estado IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET @TSQL_QUERY = @TSQL_QUERY + ' AND <coluna> = ' + @variable
END
```

... hacer esto para todos los parametros/variables

3. Al final
   EJECUTAR  @TSQL_QUERY..

Con esto lo consigo si, pero me preocupa grandemente el riesgo de SQL INJECTION por lo que no se si es una buena solución para usar en producción.

Alguien tiene una mejor idea? Existe algún otro mecanismo más seguro?

Desde ya agradecido por las respuestas.

Comment: más seguro (pero no necesariamente con mejor performance) sería usar `AND id_ciudad = @id_ciudad OR @id_ciudad IS NULL) AND (id_estado = @id_estado OR  @id_estado IS NULL)` y así sucesivamente

Comment: gracias @Lamak por tu rapida respuesta. El COALESCE y el ISNULL me resuelven el problema de la seguridad, pero me necesito algo que me ayude con las dos cosas, performance+seguridad, pues los reportes generados estan demorando mucho, es realmente desesperante esperar variso minutos por un resultado

Answer (score 0):

Tu idea es buena, pero es necesario hacerlo correctamente. Lo que tienes, se conoce en inglés como *catch-all-query* porque sirve para capturar todas las posibilidades. Por lo general, no se recomienda su uso pero sabemos que a veces son necesarias.

Existen 2 formas de hacer que funcionen de forma correcta.

- Una es usando código dinámico para agregar sólo las condiciones que necesitas. El error que cometiste fue el de concatenar valores y ello puede abrir la puerta para inyección de SQL (aunque no en este caso puesto que todos los valores eran enteros). La forma correcta es usar `sp_executesql` que permite parametrizar el código dinámico. Esta opción tiene la ventaja de que se puede reutilizar el plan guardado en caché, pero la desventaja de que puede volverse complicado cuando hay muchas variantes.

```
    CREATE  PROCEDURE MY_PROC
    (
       @id_ciudad int = null,
       @id_estado int = null,
       @id_barrio int = null,
       @id_zona_operacional int = null
    --   ... otros parametros
    )
    AS 

    DECLARE @TSQL_query  NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @Condiciones NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    --Agregamos las condiciones solo si el parámetro tiene valor        
    IF @id_ciudad IS NOT NULL
        SET @Condiciones = N'  AND id_ciudad = @id_ciudad' + NCHAR(13);

    IF @id_estado IS NOT NULL
        SET @Condiciones = N'  AND id_estado = @id_estado' + NCHAR(13);

    IF @id_barrio IS NOT NULL
        SET @Condiciones = N'  AND id_barrio = @id_barrio' + NCHAR(13);

    -- Cambiamos el primer AND por WHERE
    -- Esto no es necesario si hay alguna condición que no sea opcional
    IF @Condiciones <> ''
        SET @Condiciones = STUFF( @Condiciones, 1, 5, N'WHERE');

    -- Armamos el código completo
    SET @TSQL_query = N'
    SELECT
       result_1,
       result_2,
       ...
       result_n
    FROM
       MY_HUGE_TABLE
    ' + @Condiciones + ';';

    -- Este sirve solo para verificar que la consulta esté bien armada
    --PRINT @TSQL_query;

    -- Executamos la consulta enviando todos los parámetros aunque no se usen.
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @TSQL_query, N'@id_ciudad int, @id_estado int, @id_barrio int', @id_ciudad, @id_estado, @id_barrio;
```

- La otra opción es utilizando el hint RECOMPILE y generando las instrucciones un poco distintas. Esto tiene la ventaja de que el código queda en su forma normal, pero la desventaja de que cada ejecución tomará recursos para recompilar la consulta.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE MY_PROC
(
   @id_ciudad int = null,
   @id_estado int = null,
   @id_barrio int = null,
   @id_zona_operacional int = null,
   ... otros parametros
)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT
   result_1,
   result_2,
   ...
   result_n
FROM
   MY_HUGE_TABLE
WHERE
   (id_ciudad = @id_ciudad OR @id_ciudad IS NULL)   
and
   (id_estado = @id_estado OR @id_estado IS NULL)
and
   (id_barrio = @id_barrio IS NULL)
and
   (id_zona_operacional = @id_zona_operacional OR @id_zona_operacional IS NULL)
and
   --... algunos otros filtros
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

END
```

Dependiendo del uso que se le de, será la forma en la que puedas elegir cual opción es la mejor en tu caso.

Comment: linda respuesta @Luis Cazares. Voy a hacer varias pruebas con tus recomendaciones y luego comento